# How to sync contacts with Outlook, WITHOUT Exchange?

Tags: contacts, sync, outlook

Can anyone recommend an app to sync Outlook contacts with Android? I know there are a number of them which sync with Exchange, but I am not using Exchange.

I'm looking for something that will sync contacts as well and as easily as Google Calendar Sync handles syncing Outlook's calendar.

I've tried "Missing Sync", but it *completely* hosed Outlook.

I'm running Outlook 2010.

Comment: Are you looking for a one-time one-way sync (Outlook -> Phone), or something that will keep both places in sync all the time?

Comment: Regular syncing, just like Google Calendar Sync does for the calendar.

Comment: For what it's worth to anyone, we tried MissingSync, and it totally hosed the data and wound up deleting all our contacts. Had to restore a PST backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're happy using Google/GMail as an intermediary for the sync, if you've already tried Google Calendar Sync, if so then there are a few options.

It sounds unlikely from your question, but if you're part of an organisation that's given  you a paid-for Google Apps account then [Google Apps Sync](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=153866&topic=23333&ctx=topic) is available for you. This syncs an Outlook Calendar, Contacts and Mail with a Google Apps GMail account, and from there you can easily sync with your phone. Unfortunately this isn't available for standard GMail/Google Accounts, or for free Google Apps accounts.

Other, third party, options to sync Outlook with a GMail account are [GO Contact Sync](http://www.webgear.co.nz/Products/GOContactSync.aspx) (free), [CompanionLink](http://www.companionlink.com/google/outlook/) (paid app) or [Goosync](http://www.goosync.com/Features.aspx) (subscription service with free trial).

Comment: The Google Apps I've actually seen, and it looked rather intriguing, ... but from what I could gather from the website, it seems it is only available for corporates/educational institutions, no?

Comment: @eidylon unfortunately yes, it really would make sense to make it available to all, must be a Marketing decision. Didn't I make that clear from the first and last sentences in the second para? I'll see if I can edit to make that clearer.

Comment: Well, you said that it was paid, but that doesn't necessarily equate to not being open to the general public. Oh well... would be nice if they opened it to the public.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Go Contact Sync](http://jameslam.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/sync-contacts-between-microsoft-outlook-and-gmail/), there are some mixed reviews on that site about it. On the other hand, I have read good things about [gSyncIt](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/index.shtml), but it is not free. It will sync calendars, contacts, tasks, and notes.

These are not specific to android, as the information is actually syncing with Google Contacts, not your device.

Answer (score 4):

I use [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/de/) on windows7 to sync outlook 2010 with my android phone.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using ‘Blue SyncRoid’ to sync my contacts and calendars between Outlook and Android via Bluetooth. Used to forget my USB cable and unwilling to share my personal information (contacts and calendars) on the cloud to sync my info. Pretty satisfied with the solution. Simple and user friendly.
They also have a trial version launched. Highly recommended. Visit http://www.bluesyncroid.com for more details. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize with Hotmail since Hotmail supports exchange and you can use the Outlook connector to connect Outlook to Hotmail.